# ImportError: No module named - python anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, github, anaconda

I just want to run the code given there: https://github.com/skaae/lasagne-draw

This is the directory structure of the file lasagne-draw-master after downloading:

```
lasagne-draw-master\

    -->\deepmodels
        --> __init__.py, batchiterator.py, confusionmatrix.py
        -->\layers
             --> __init__.py, draw.py, draw_helpers.py, draw_helpers_test.py

    -->\examples
        --> mnist_draw.py, helper_functions.py
```

For installation I have to do these steps after installing Theano and Lasagne as mentioned in readme file there. I am on lasagne-draw-master directory too.

```
python setup.py develop

cd ..

python -c 'import deepmodels'
```

The above two commands executed perfectly. But when i execute the third command, it shows me this error:

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "deepmodels\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  from . import layers
File "deepmodels\layers\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  from .base import *
ImportError: No module named base
```

The content of deepmodels__init__.py is:

```
from . import confusionmatrix
from . import layers
from . import batchiterator
```

The content of deepmodels\layers__init__.py is:

```
from .base import *
from .draw import *
```

I am using python anaconda. Is there any syntax error in **init**.py files or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out the issues and solved these by following modifications in both init.py and draw.py(in layers directory) file.

```
deepmodels/init.py

change followings

from . import confusionmatrix
from . import layers
from . import batchiterator

to follows; 

import confusionmatrix
import layers
import batchiterator

deepmodels/layers/init.py

change followings 

from .base import *
from .draw import *

to as follows; 

from lasagne.layers.base import *
from draw import *

deepmodels/layers/draw.py

line 8
comment out from .. import logdists
```